# 410 for chinese spam links in .htaccess? Recrawling on GSC

Tags: google-search-console, spam, 410-gone

A clients site has been facing a chinese spam links attack. With ~100k spam links already created, with many indexed, before we were onboarded.

The links all have either of these two in the slug

/search/

/?s=

before something like this `=潮州高端外围快餐+微443534687+电V同步156-7495-7007+全城安排潮州高端外围快餐+微443534687+电V同步156-7495-7007+全城安排3`

so the complete url looks like `https://myurl . com/?s=潮州高端外围快餐+微443534687+电V同步156-7495-7007+全城安排潮州高端外围快餐+微443534687+电V同步156-7495-7007+全城安排3`

To figure out what was going on, we had sucuri check the site for malware - nothing found

We blocked both these search operator using robots.txt.

Next we had these links go to 404, using .htaccess. Both these controlled links getting indexed to some extent. Removed sitemap from GSC and reupped it, fed home page to check url for a recrawl, hoping 404's will drop out.

A week went by and none of the links dropped. So, created a rule sending everything with these two to 410

/search/

/?s=

Here's the .htaccess now. Two days gone and nothing changes in GSC. The site's rankings have disappeared and traffic is almost 0 now. Those pages with chinese links go to 410 Gone now, how do we get GSC to drop those links?

#block `https://myurl . com/?s=*` type URLs with 410 status
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=
RewriteRule ^ - [R=410,L]

#block `https://myurl . com/*/search/` type URLs with 410 status
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?search(/.*)?$ - [R=410,NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/search/(.*) - [R=410,NC,L]

I have also attached the screenshot from google search console below. Those 16.1k indexed links contain almost 6k chinese spam links that we are trying to get rid of, and the 84k not indexed are 99% spam links

I will appreciate any advise on how to tackle this and also if you could take a look at the .htaccess and let me know any changes that i could make to handle this better.

Much appreciated! Thank you,

[image: screen shot from google search console]